# JPA Bulk update not working

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I need to do bulk updates using id's in JPA. 
I have tried using the following query in Postgres and its working fine:

```
 update DUMMY set dlr='1' and time='2017-05-15 10:00:00' IN ids ('30c7a7cc-e807-4f0a-bbc9-baee8ad91ec7','ae1e6e47-839f-4858-baa2-6b142815a236','c9d44b84-a8e7-4c57-a498-df2f96752049','8f858543-c28a-414b-9eb9-70e35bbbde66','dda28cc5-1024-4986-85c6-822d9173e09e');
```

In the above query i am updating records having the id's in the array and set the dlr and time.

I am trying the same query via JPA :

```
queryStm = "Update DUMMY set dlr=:dlr,time=:time,serverTime=:servertime  where id IN :arrids ";


Query query  = em.createNativeQuery(queryStm);
            query.setParameter("arrids ",arrids );
            query.setParameter("dlr", dlr);
            query.setParameter("time", time);
            query.setParameter("servertime", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));

            query.executeUpdate();
```

The array has 100 id's but it updates only 20-30 records.

Is there something wrong in the way i am doing it.

I am using Postgres 9.6.2 version and using the following dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `IN ids [...]` is invalid. The query can't possibly work

Comment: Not Sure, But Hibernate can uses an outdated version of the entity if you fetched it from the database before you executed the native SQL UPDATE statement. try doing  `em.flush();` and  `em.detach(entity)` before  `em.createNativeQuery`.

Comment: @parladneupane tried that but its not working

Comment: why is this a native query and not JPQL BULK UPDATE?